# bash variable substitution not working on Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris, gnu, substitution, variable-expansion

I have this code snippet running on several Linux boxes, and a Solaris 10 box with bash 3.6 (iirc).  However, on a Solaris 11 box, with `GNU bash, version 4.4.11(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.11)` it gives the following error.

```
#!/bin/env bash
CLEAN_COUNT() {
    local L_STRING=$(sed '/[^[:graph:][:space:]]/{
        s/[^[:graph:][:space:]]//g; s/\[[0-9]*m//g; s/(B//g
        }' <<<$*) || return 1

    echo ${#L_STRING}
}

f() {
   ARGS=($@)
   echo $((${#ARGS[1]:-0} - $(CLEAN_COUNT ${ARGS[1]:-0}) ))
}

f one two three four
```

Error received: `./gather_data.bash: line 15: ${#ARGS[1]:-0} - $(CLEAN_COUNT ${ARGS[1]:-0}) : bad substitution`

I've isolated the above code in it's own script, I've compared the shopt and `set -o` settings on that box with another one.  I'm perplexed.  If I can get the code to work without the substitution, even if ARGS has no element 1 and I'm running `set -o nounset`, then I will use another piece of code.

Comment: Does it run in bash, or sh?

Comment: What is this supposed to do `${#ARGS[1]:-0}`? `${#...}` can't be null or unset if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Btw.: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: bash, ${#ARGS[1]:-0} will return a zero if there is no element 1 (that is the substitution), I use shellchecker-- nothing that helps

Comment: `#` is for the number of elements, you don't want that in there.

Comment: /bin/env bash finds bash @ /usr/bin/bash

Comment: Or is it supposed to be "number of characters in element at index 1, and 0 if not defined?" because arithmetic context already does "0 if not defined" anyway.

Comment: Ben, ${#ARRAY[@]} is number of elements, ${#ARRAY[1]} is the length of that element.  The ${#ARGS[1]:-0} is being used b/c the script this comes from uses `set -o nounset` and it avoids the "variable unset" error.  I'm running this to debug the problem w/o nounset (or the rest of the script) and it gives me this error.

Comment: Does `${#var:-something}` really work for you anywhere? It doesn't for me.

Comment: Per beginning of the question-- it works everywhere except one box.  It works on Solaris 10, Linux, bash 3.6, bash 4.2, just not on a single Solaris 11 running the above version of bash

Comment: I ran `echo ${#var:-1}` in Docker containers for Bash 4.4, 4.3, 4.2, 4.1, 4.0 and 3.2. It's bad substitution everywhere.

Comment: Ben, I'm not doing ${#var:-1}, I'm doing ${#var[1]:-0}  An array, vs. a single variable

Comment: @PesaThe, with `set -o nounset`, if you remove the `:-0` part and the element is unset set, you get the following error: `line 15: ARGS[1]: unbound variable`

Comment: Why would `${#var[1]:-1}` work if `${var#:-1}` doesn't? I'll try it, but I'd be extremely surprised.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now. Adding answer in a bit.

Comment: Interested in seeing it.  I just came up with a rather ugly work around, but I'm hoping yours is better (regardless, if it works, I'll give you the check-mark, so to speak)

Comment: @SaintHax Oh, I forgot about the `nounset` :) Not sure what the problem is but another workaround could be: `tmp=${ARGS[1]-}` and then `${#tmp}`.

Comment: `${#var[1]:0-}` is, at best, undefined. There is nothing the documentation that suggests you should be able to combine `${#...}` with `${...:-...}`.

Comment: @chepner, I'm not seeing how that helps solve the problem.

Comment: Do you ever access elements other than the first two in `f()`? Because if not, there is no need for an array like `ARGS`.

Comment: @Ben, yes... the function should be passed 4 or 5 (optional 5th) arguments each time it's called.  The rest of the code is missing, since it wasn't the problematic part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes affecting this happened in Bash 4.3 and Bash 4.4. Observe:

- No error in Bash 4.2:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm -it bash:4.2 bash -u
  bash-4.2$ bash --version | head -n 1
  GNU bash, version 4.2.53(2)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-musl)
  bash-4.2$ declare -a var && echo "${#var[1]:-1}"
  0
  ```

  but this doesn't actually print my default value: `var[1]` is the empty string, hence `0`. `-u` seems to ignore that `var` has no elements. There is no difference in behaviour between `echo "${#var[1]:-1}"`, `echo "${#var[1]}"` and `echo "${#var[1]}"`, they all print `0`.
- Bash 4.3 complains about unbound variable:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm -it bash:4.3 bash -u
  bash-4.3$ bash --version | head -n 1
  GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-musl)
  bash-4.3$ declare -a var && echo "${#var[1]:-1}"
  bash: var: unbound variable
  ```
- Bash 4.4 complains about substitution:

  ```
  $ docker run --rm -it bash:4.4 bash -u
  bash-4.4$ bash --version | head -n 1
  GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-musl)
  bash-4.4$ declare -a var && echo "${#var[1]:-1}"
  bash: ${#var[1]:-1}: bad substitution
  ```

  even without `set -u`:

  ```
  bash-4.4# set +o nounset
  bash-4.4# declare -a var && echo "${#var[1]:-1}"
  bash: ${#var[1]:-1}: bad substitution
  ```

Also, `${#var:-1}` is considered "bad substitution" in all versions, even without `set -u`:

```
$ for v in 3.2 4.{0..4}; do docker run --rm -it bash:$v; done
bash-3.2# echo "${#var:-1}"
bash: ${#var:-1}: bad substitution
bash-3.2# exit
exit
bash-4.0# echo "${#var:-1}"
bash: ${#var:-1}: bad substitution
bash-4.0# exit
exit
bash-4.1# echo "${#var:-1}"
bash: ${#var:-1}: bad substitution
bash-4.1# exit
exit
bash-4.2# echo "${#var:-1}"
bash: ${#var:-1}: bad substitution
bash-4.2# exit
exit
bash-4.3# echo "${#var:-1}"
bash: ${#var:-1}: bad substitution
bash-4.3# exit
exit
bash-4.4# echo "${#var:-1}"
bash: ${#var:-1}: bad substitution
bash-4.4# exit
exit
```

I can't see any mention of changes to this behaviour in [`NEWS`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS), but it seems to make sense, as `${#var[0]:-1}` doesn't default to `1` anyway, so now the behaviour is consistent across scalars and arrays.

This being said, I'd rewrite your function as follows:

```
f () {
    local args=("$@")
    if [[ -z ${args[1]:-} ]]; then
        echo 0
    else
        echo $(( ${#args[1]} - $(clean_count "${args[1]}") ))
    fi
}
```

- Rename uppercase variable names to lowercase to avoid clash with shell and environment variables
- Make `args` local to function
- Quote `"$@"` in args to avoid splitting before assigning to array elements
- Check if `args[1]` is the empty string, make sure no unset complaint is triggered with `${args[1]:-}`
- Treat cases for empty and non-empty string separately

---

Alternatively, if `f ()` is not a simplification and you never access elements other than what you show, you could further simplify to

```
f () {
    if [[ -z ${2:-} ]]; then
        echo 0
    else
        echo $(( ${#2} - $(clean_count "$2") ))
    fi
}
```

Comment: Why do we even need `args`? Just use `$2` instead of `${args[1]}`.

Comment: @chepner Good point; if `f()` really is this short and never does anything with any other arguments, we don't need it at all.

Comment: @chepner, that was the work around I had in mind I mentioned earlier.  It takes a max of 5 arguments, so I just used `ARGS[0]=${1:-}` so that I avoid substitution with the array's element.  At this point I could have changed the array to a variable, but there was more code that already written and I needed to get a fix to a client quickly.